# having with connecting to site from command line

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, curl

I am able to connect to following
https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json
using a browser

When I try to connect to it from command line

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to registry.terraform.io port 443: Timed
>   out

any ideas on how to resolve it
thanks

Comment: What is your _curl_ Command-Line?

Comment: Please update the title, as I'm assuming you meant to type "Having _an issue_ with..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue was with incorrect settings of proxy on command window
HTTPS_PROXY=proxy settings from browser

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

Try the `curl` command listed below in Step 7. If that doesn't work, you likely have another issue besides your `curl` command (such as a firewall or proxy).

**Copying Browser Requests with cURL**

If you can connect with a browser, one way to eliminate potential issues with your `curl` command is to "copy" the desired transaction from your browser. Chrome, Firefox, and Opera all have a Developer console which allows this.

1. Open an new blank tab.
2. In Chrome and Firefox, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the Developer console. In Opera, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.
3. Look for the `Network` option and select it.
4. Navigate to your desired URL e.g. https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json.
5. You should end up looking at something similar to the following:

   *ex. Network Transactions*

   [image: Firefox Developer Console - Network Transactions - Screenshot]
6. Select the desired transaction, right-click and select the option to `Copy as cURL` (for Chrome, use `Copy as cURL (cmd)`).

   *ex. Copy as cURL*

   [image: Firefox Developer Console - Network Transactions - Copy as cURL - Screenshot]
7. If you paste the contents of the clipboard, you should have an exact copy of the request for `curl`:

   ```
   curl "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json" -H "authority: registry.terraform.io" -H "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1" -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36" -H "sec-fetch-mode: navigate" -H "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3" -H "sec-fetch-site: none" -H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9" --compressed
   ```

This `curl` command should replicate the request made by the browser exactly.

**Other Issues**

Assuming that this doesn't solve the problem, then you will have to look into other reasons why this request might be failing, such as firewall/proxy issues or certificate issues.

- Use the `-k` or `--insecure` option to ignore self-signed or invalid certificates with curl.
- Consider using the `--verbose` flag, as well as dumping HTTP headers with `-D -`, with `curl` to aid troubleshooting.

---

**Emulating A Specific Browser**

Based on your additional comment that your (generic) cURL requests are still failing, it's likely you will need to emulate the specific browser which can connect successfully.

Browsers identify themselves with a [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string associated with a given version of that browser. If you want to emulate the browser that can connect to your URL, you'll need to either:

1. Use the steps I give under *Copying Browser Requests with cURL* in the browser that can connect successfully.
2. Try replacing the `user-agent` value in Step 7 with the value returned from a site like [What Is My Browser](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent) (visit this link in the browser which has no trouble accessing your link).

***Example (Option 2)***

*"Generic" User Agent (above)*

```
-H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36"
```

*Specific User Agent (e.g. from What Is My Browser)*

```
-H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
```

---

*It's important to note that the first method (copying the request) is probably the most reliable, as it may catch headers other than the `user-agent` that are used to authorize a request.*

---

Comment: thank you, https://registry.terraform.io    Trying 151.101.50.49...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 151.101.50.49 port 443 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to registry.terraform.io port 443: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to registry.terraform.io port 443: Timed out

Comment: You are likely going to want to actually copy the request from the browser then, as I detail in Steps 1-7. You can also use a site like [What Is My Browser](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent) to detect the actual `user-agent` string of the browser that can connect successfully. You could then try replacing just the `user-agent` header in your `curl` request in Step 7. That said, copying the request from the browser directly is probably the most reliable solution (as it may catch headers other than the `user-agent` used to authorize a request).

Comment: Note that if neither of the options above work for you, your are likely going to need to edit your question to include actual information about your `curl`/network environment (e.g. what version of `curl` are you using, OS, do you use a proxy, have you allowed `curl` through your firewall(s), etc.).